# Variables dependency using Combine

Tags: ios, swift, infinite-loop, combine

I have a class with two variables depending on each other. If one variable changes it should change the other and vice versa.

I am using the Combine framework in iOS Swift. So with `sink` I am listening/subscribe to changes of the publisher.

```
var store = Set<AnyCancellable>()
class Obs: ObservableObject {
    @Published var pub: Int = 0
}
let ob1 = Obs()
let ob2 = Obs()
    
ob1.$pub
    .dropFirst()  // ignore initial assignment
    .sink { num in
        if ob2.pub != num {
            ob2.pub = num
        }
    }.store(in: &store)
    
ob2.$pub
    .dropFirst()
    .sink { num in
        if ob1.pub != num {
            ob1.pub = num
        }
    }.store(in: &store)
    
ob1.pub = 1
```

With this code I get a stack overflow. How can I break the "infinite loop"?

Should I use something like semaphores? Or some kind of flag within a tuple? Or are there some special combine filter? Or any other ideas...?

I think I may have some general misunderstanding of the problem...

Comment: One has to be the original source, they can not both be that.

Comment: you can use a separate subject to update based on the pub value.

Answer (score 0):

The "problem" is that publishers have [willSet semantics](https://forums.swift.org/t/is-this-a-bug-in-published/31292/69), i.e. the `pub` variable will first publish the new value and then the variable `pub` will change its value. So the condition `ob1.pub != num` that reads the ob1 value will never be false.

In order to send the value after the variable has been updated you modify the publisher to `receive(on:)` a scheduler:

```
ob1.$pub
    .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
    .dropFirst()
    .sink { num in
        if ob2.pub != num {
            ob2.pub = num
        }
    }.store(in: &store)

ob2.$pub
    .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
    .dropFirst()
    .sink { num in
        if ob1.pub != num {
            ob1.pub = num
        }
    }.store(in: &store)

ob1.pub = 1
```

Comment: great explanation to understand what is going on/wrong

Comment: @Laufwunder Thank you, you can accept it if you think it will be useful to others too.

Answer (score 0):

I got a workaround with the Combine operators `scan` and `compactMap`. So I can compare the new value with the previous/old one. If the new value and the old value are equal the published value is transformed to `nil` and dropped/ignored with `compactMap`.

```
var store = Set<AnyCancellable>()
class Obs: ObservableObject {
   @Published var pub: Int = 0
}
let ob1 = Obs()
let ob2 = Obs()
    
ob1.$pub
    // new >>>
    .scan(ob1.pub) {
        $0 == $1 ? nil : $1
    }
    .compactMap { $0 }
    // <<<
    .sink { num in
        if ob2.pub != num {
            ob2.pub = num
        }
    }.store(in: &store)
    
ob2.$pub
    // new >>>
    .scan(ob2.pub) {
        $0 == $1 ? nil : $1
    }
    .compactMap { $0 }
    // <<<
    .sink { num in
        if ob1.pub != num {
            ob1.pub = num
        }
    }.store(in: &store)
```

This helped me to break the loop in my case.